# How to map a oracle defined user types to JPA entity using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, jpa-2.0

I work with oracle 10g and I use the concepts of composite types, nested table and varray. For example I created a type `adress` and a table person using pl/sql :

```
create type adress as object (ville varchar2(10),zip varchar2(10));
create type persontype as object (idp varchar2(5),name varchar2(10),personadress adress);
create table person of persontype;
```

Now I have to generate the  entity class from the person table. The problem that JPA and Hibernate maps only the basic types as `number` and `varchar`. How to map the attribute personadress ?

Answer (score -1):

For mapping any entity in hibernate, you need to use `<many-to-one>` or collections as per your requirement.

[This link about Mapping in the Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Think you for your help but this link is not helpful

Comment: The OP is asking about mapping an Oracle user defined type to a JPA entity. At the time of the question, JPA didn't support UDTs, but with JPA 2.1 in 2013 it now does. Whether the specific JPA provider supports them is another matter - with [TopLink](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/TopLink) and [EclipseLink](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/EclipseLink) including extended support for Oracle.